# nginx errors: upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx server with 5 backend servers. We serve around 400-500 requests/second. I have started getting a large number of Upstream Timed out errors (110: Connection timed out)

Error string in error.log looks like

`2011/01/10 21:59:46 [error] 1153#0: *1699246778 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: {IP}, server: {domain}, request: "GET {URL} HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://{backend_server}:80/{url}", host: "{domain}", referrer: "{referrer}"`

Any suggestions how to debug such errors. I am unable to find a munin plugin to keep a check on number of upstream errors. Sometime the number of errors per day is way too high and somedays its a more decent 3 digit number. A munin graph would probably help us finding out any pattern or correlation with anything else

How can we make the number of such error as ZERO

Comment: This error is related to your backends not responding fast enough. You should not be looking at Nginx for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin said, this error belong to your backends, although you can make sure that you don't queue too much requests on a failed backend and get a good overview of backend status with haproxy and its queueing and healthchecking capabilities. Logging of upstream response time in nginx ($upstream_response_time) can be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Problem, but mine came from not having the `/etc/hosts` setup properly for my domain.

I needed to add the FQDN and just the hostname associated to the IP address of my domain. For example,

```
192.168.100.57 support.domain.com support
```

Note how the IP is mapped to the FQDN, as well as just it's hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs for your backend servers. The problem could be on the network, but it's far more likely that your backend servers are taking too long and timing out.